# Azure Data Factory - What could be best way to create a pipeline to read and loop through 10 million of data from Azure SQL table?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Azure SQL server Table, I would like to read data from one sql table and select 4-5 columns(total rows could be more than a million). Once I have the records, I have to loop through to send a message to Azure service bus queue. it will be once message per record fetched.

Current solution is using a Lookup to read data and save data to a variable. Then Foreach looping on that variable to send message to the service bus queue. (This could be slow with performance.)

Comment: Lookup has a limit of 5000 rows, so I don't think that will work. I honestly don't know if Data Factory is a good solution for this problem as it isn't really intended to operate over individual rows like this.

Answer (score 0):

> The **ForEach Activity** defines a repeating control flow in an Azure
> Data Factory or Synapse pipeline. This activity is used to iterate
> over a collection and executes specified activities in a loop. The
> loop implementation of this activity is similar to Foreach looping
> structure in programming languages.

I think you need to drive the foreach via a SQL lookup task that populates a data set and then call the activity for each row:

I recommend you to accumulate the details given in below official documents for your requirement.

[ForEach activity in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity)

[Lookup activity in Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity)

Tutorial: [Copy multiple tables in bulk by using Azure Data Factory in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal)

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to loop through 10 million records, I don't think ADF lookup activity is a feasible approach as it has [few limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#limitations-and-workarounds). You may try exploring [Lookup transformation in Mapping Data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-lookup) in ADF and see if that fits your requirement, else would recommend using a different ETL service which supports looping through 10million records.